Phrase out of figures
The answer is a phrase. What phrase?



First

 you take the ‘y distance’ and then the ‘x-distance’ from each of the same shapes of the same colour starting from the triangle and then the subsequent shapes with a +1 increase of sides each time.

Then

 You concatenate it into numbers and finally then convert it into letters using the A1Z26 cipher.

For example

 
 (1,5) is 15 which is O, (0,6) is 6 which is F making ‘OF’.

Doing so you get

 SLOPE OF LINES


That doesn't look quite right. Given the colour schemes it looks like it would be (5,2,5) instead (and I think I would then reverse the words as you have presented them).

Oops typo my bad

My inclination would be to reverse the words from the way you have them (but I guess either way could work) +1

Nice job! You got the correct words, but as hexomino says the phrase was intended to be S o L
